# Como criar um Objeto JSON em Delphi

Tags: json, delphi

Eu estou tentando criar um JSON com valores que foram preenchido pelo usuário. Até agora eu tenho isso, mas não está funcionando

```
procedure TOAuth2TesterFrm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    nome_evento: String;
    inicio: String;
    fim: String;
    objeto: TJSONObject;
begin
    objeto.AddPair('nome',nome_evento);
    objeto.AddPair('data_inicio',inicio);
    objeto.AddPair('data_fim',fim);
    LogMem.Text:=TJSON.ObjectToJsonString(objeto);
```

Answer (score 3):

Pelo pouco que sei, está faltando instanciar o objeto antes de usar ele.
Tente

```
var
  objeto: TJSONObject;
begin
  objeto := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    objeto.AddPair('nome' , nome_evento);
    objeto.AddPair('data_inicio' , inicio);

  finally
    objeto.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Está faltando instanciar seu objeto:

```
objeto := TJSONObject.Create;
```

Lembre-se também de destruir o mesmo para não dar memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de usar

```
LogMem.Text:=TJSON.ObjectToJsonString(objeto);
```

Tente

```
LogMem.Text := objeto.ToString;
```

ou

```
LogMem.Text := objeto.ToJSON;
```